# Prestashop Cart Summary : Custom code is disabled when quantities added

Tags: cart, prestashop-1.6

I modified the shopping-cart-product-line.tpl, so that it displays the product price with and without tax in the cart summary.

With Tax : price=$product.price_wt

Without Tax : price=$product.price

```
<li class="price priceDark{if isset($product.is_discounted) &&    $product.is_discounted && isset($product.reduction_applies) && $product.reduction_applies} special-price{/if}">{convertPrice price=$product.price_wt} TTC</li>

<li class="price{if isset($product.is_discounted) && $product.is_discounted && isset($product.reduction_applies) && $product.reduction_applies} {/if}">{convertPrice price=$product.price} HT</li>
```

[image]

It's working fine, but the line without tax disappears when I change the quantity.

So do the "TTC" and "HT" legends.

[image]

Might be that my comments are not included in some other file but I'm a bit lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at your_theme/js/cart-summary.js file. And I think you should edit updateCartSummary function. Its place where your summary is updating. Other thing: addd new

or  with different class. It should`nt remove unit price wihout VAT, but also it always stay same price. So you must add line to count sum: price_tax_excl * quantity.

So briefly, you must edit or extend your cart-sumarry.js file.

Comment: Just add to edit a bit of code in cart-summary.js to make it work. Thanks for showing me the way ;)